# getting an error Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im basically trying to get a form to search from multiple fields on my form but keep getting the error 
database_conn

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('xxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxxx');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "<p>Connection failed:".mysqli_connect_error()."</p>\n";
}
?>
```

php updated - the error I get now is  "Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object"

```
<?php

include 'database_conn.php';



$shoeSize = isset($_GET['shoeSize']) ? $_GET['shoeSize'] : null ;
$brandID = isset($_GET['brandID']) ? $_GET['brandID'] : null ;
$gender = isset($_GET['gender']) ? $_GET['gender'] : null ;

$sqlShoes = "SELECT shoeSize, brandID, gender FROM sh_shoe WHERE 1";

$sqlCondition = "";

IF($shoeSize != null ) {
    $sqlCondition = $sqlCondition . "SELECT shoeSize FROM sh_shoe WHERE 1 AND shoeSize = $shoeSize";
}
IF($brandID != null ) {
    $sqlCondition = $sqlCondition . "SELECT brandID FROM sh_shoe WHERE 1 AND brandID = $brandID";
}
IF($gender != null ) {
    $sqlCondition = $sqlCondition . "SELECT gender FROM sh_shoe WHERE 1 AND gender = $gender";
}

$sqlSearch = $sqlShoes . $sqlCondition;

$result = $mysqli->query($sqlSearch);

$rowShoes = $result->fetch_assoc();
// then to output
echo "<p>{$rowShoes['shoeSize']}</p>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Seeing where `$mysqli` is defined initially would be a good place to start. Some issues that also could be causes for your code failing are...</s>

`$mysqli` is not an object it is an empty variable defined at the `global` line. `global` is used to make a variable accessible in a function, it doesn't appear you need that.

Your connection currently is `$conn`. That is built procedurally though. Your code is using the object approach so I think in your db file change the `$conn` line to:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('xxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxxx');
```

Unless you are using `$conn` in other files. If this is your first file this should be fine.

Additionally:

The `+` does not concatenate in PHP, that is JS syntax I believe. The `.` is how to concatenate.

Once that is corrected though your queries will be built incorrectly. You would have a built query as

```
SELECT shoeSize, brandID, gender FROM sh_shoe WHERE 1SELECT shoeSize FROM sh_shoe WHERE 1 AND shoeSize = $shoeSize
```

You need to separate out the user input and only append the columns you want to search on to the query.

A rough untested answer which should also close up that SQL injection whole is.

```
include 'database_conn.php';
global $mysqli;
$query = "SELECT shoeSize, brandID, gender FROM sh_shoe";
if(!empty($_GET['shoeSize'])) {
    $where[] = ' shoeSize = ' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['shoeSize']);
}
if(!empty($_GET['brandID'])) {
    $where[] = ' brandID =  ' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['brandID']);
}
if(!empty($_GET['gender'])) {
    $where[] = ' gender = ' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['gender']);
}
if(!empty($where)) {
    $query = $query . ' WHERE ' . implode(' and ', $where);
}
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

This also presumes all fields were integers as your original queries did. If they are not the inputs should be surrounded by single quotes.

If `$_GET['gender']` is `male`/`female` that should be:

```
if(!empty($_GET['gender'])) {
    $where[] = ' gender = \'' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['gender']) . "'";
}
```

because without the quotes the query is

```
gender = male
```

which is invalid.

```
gender = 'male'
```

is the correct query.

Comment: isn't it just a non object reference with $mysqli, albeit an alleged global ? Then again as you say, concat could be the issue

Comment: Oh, yea, I thought the failure was on a `fetch` of a presumed result object.

Comment: The bottom of the code is my problem i think    $result = $mysqli->query($sqlSearch);  it says method query not found in class

Comment: 1. Where/how is `$mysqli` originally defined. 2. What is the exact error message? The message above says non-object..

Comment: it says the non-object error on line 28 when i press submit on my form and it says the method query not found in class in the editor

Comment: Can you update the question with where you define `$mysqli`?

Comment: global $mysqli;? at the top

Comment: That allows the `$mysqli` variable defined outside your function to be used in your function. See here for a longer write up on global, http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. That doesn't create you a `mysqli` object which it sounds like is the issue.

Comment: sorry bit of a rookie and i am confused

Comment: If you only have `global $mysqli;` then you have not created a `mysqli` connection. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php `database_conn.php` must have something in there, right?

Comment: ok i have updated the question with the database_conn.php file

Comment: Okay, that's your issue. `$conn` is your connection that also is not an object.

Comment: how would I fix this?

Comment: you need to remember Lowell that these interfaces have procedural and object-oriented functions. So you need to do a $mysqli=new mysql(...) to have an object. The variable name must be $mysqli (or whatever, but be consistent)

Comment: Added update to answer. The update is at the top of the answer...maybe I should have put it at the bottom? Seemed to make more sense at the top.

Comment: thanks just seen your updated answer not coming up with any errors now, any help on how i would display the results of the search?

Comment: Oh and thank you guys so much for the help its really appreciated

Comment: You'll need to fetch the result and iterate through them. You might want to take a look at a tutorial. Here's one, http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/using-object-oriented-php-with-the-mysqli-extension/. I think this question is resolved now though. If tis is resolved please be sure to accept the answer.

Comment: working through the turorial that you gave me and i am still confused by the whole non-object thing using this code at the end:     $rowShoes =     $result->fetch_assoc();
     // then to output 
    echo "<p>{$rowShoes['shoeSize']}</p>"; I still get the same problem

Comment: Can you update your question again? Hard to say from that example.

Comment: Look at the queries I wrote and look at yours.  Your queries are all going to fail.

Comment: its just I have no idea what your queries are doing because i have learnt nothing about real escape string

Comment: Even without the real escape look at the differences. Also look at the manual reference for real escape. A better approach is prepared statements.